# Getting version code for About screen

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Is there any way to get the version code from my project settings to use on my About screen?

Project structure/app/Flavours has both a Version Code and a Version Name. Is there any way I can "inject" either one into a text field that appears on my About screen? I'm thinking of the same technique you use to put variables in other text messages, like "Order number %1$s has been deleted as per your request" which gets filled in via

```
getString(R.string.message01, orderNumber)
```

or something similar.

If the technique for the version code is the same, what would I use to get the version code or name in the above code?

I'm running Android Studio 3.1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your version name and code by using the `BuildConfig` class.

```
int code = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
String name = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

Or as you want to use it:

```
<string name="version_example">App version: %1$s</string>
```

```
getString(R.string.version_example, BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
```

The  `BuildConfig` class gets auto-generated at compile time depending on your Gradle config. You can also use it to define custom fields, see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#simplify-app-development

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful :-)